# How to disable this useless message in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows, user-interface

Every time I click Network, I get a message in a pale yellow drop-down box that says,

```
Network discovery and file sharing are turned off.  Network computers and devices are not visible.  Click to change...
```

[image: message]

I know that these things are turned off, because I turned them off myself.

How can I make this useless message stop appearing?

**Edit:** I have *already* turned off network discovery and file sharing.  That's not the problem.  I want to turn off the useless message, while leaving network discovery and file sharing turned off.

Comment: Why do you even click Network, if you have network discovery and file sharing disabled? Am I missing something here?

Comment: Network should include things that I have explicitly added or connected to, such as Novell Connections, the tree, and so on.

Comment: +1 for screenshot with excellent Paint modification :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

execute this command  `sc config SSDPSRV start=disabled`

Comment: `sc config SSDPSRV start= disabled` space is needed after `start= `. i tried to edit the answer but S.O wont allow me to change only a `space`.

Comment: this comand is not helping me.

Comment: You do have to run it as an admin and possibly elevated.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried switching them from off to on and then back?

I think it is turned off by default, but Windows will probably keep reminding you to choose between on or off yourself.

Comment: Now I see, I thought the settings said: turn the settings off, as in changing the default off to really off.